How to change file path in BAT file based on the current user?
I have a bat file to run some Python code similar to this:
@echo off
set /P State=                         Select State:
set /P Year=                          Select Year:

"C:\Users\MYNUMBER\OneDrive - Company\filepath\python.exe" "C:\Users\MYNUMBER\OneDrive - Company\filepath\tst.py" %State% %Year% 
pause

I want different people at my organization to be able to run this file without any issue, but currently the path specifies my User number (called MYNUMBER).
What is the best way to make this bat file runnable for anyone in the company?

Can't you use %USERNAME%?

How exactly would I include this in the string though?

Your "user number" is your username (that it's a number is incidental).

Whoever decided to downvote this, please offer an explanation - it is simply inane to downvote without context or reason. I am asking a genuine question as someone who is new to bat scripting

@ChanganAuto sorry but this isn't clear to me. Yes using %USERNAME% will give the current users name/number, but my question is HOW to integrate this into the string.

In your script, replace MYNUMBER with %USERNAME%

Just to make you aware, this was also posted over on StackOverflow. Jwem93, please do not do that, this site was a better choice IMO.

From my comment there... 'Just be aware, that you could also use %OneDriveCommercial% for this, although %OneDrive%, should always be correct for the currently logged-in user. So simply change it to either "%OneDrive%\filepath\python.exe" "%OneDrive%\filepath\tst.py" %State% %Year%, or "%OneDriveCommercial%\filepath\python.exe" "%OneDriveCommercial%\filepath\tst.py" %State% %Year%. I should also say that you should be very careful using unchecked and unquoted user input like that.'

There are several environment variables that you can use. Pick the one that works for you. Of course, every user should have python.exe in their OneDrive folder.
"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive - Company\filepath\python.exe"
"%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive - Company\filepath\python.exe"
"%ONEDRIVE%\filepath\python.exe"

Do not assume that the user's profile directory will always be C:\Users\%USERNAME%. Neither on personal systems (it won't work after account rename, it won't work for many people logging in with a MS account) nor on corporate systems (various mess like username.domain will happen; and again, accounts get renamed and shuffled around). That's why %USERPROFILE% exists.

@grawity_u1686 That's exactly why I gave more options. %ONEDRIVE% also does not work in all cases
